# need information on creating swap memory on unix

Tags: linux, filesystems, memory, swap

I am creating swap file using `fallocate -l "$memory" "$swapfilename"` command.

I have some questions:

1. On which file system is the swap file created if multiple file systems are present? Can we externally specify from which file system to take?
2. I have two file systems `tmpfs` and `rootfs`, and by default swap file is created by using rootfs memory; even tmpfs has more size. What is tmpfs?
3. Before creating swap file how to check if space is there or not?

```
[root@rhev6 scripts]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs          3.1G  2.8G  123M  96% /
tmpfs           1.5G   76K  1.5G   1% /dev/shm
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file is created in the directory indicated by `$swapfilename`, by default the current directory. The command `fallocate` has no idea of what you want to do with the file; it just creates it and allocates the amount of space requested. To use the file as a paging area you need to run `mkswap` on it.

**tmpfs** is a memory-based file system used for (small) temporary files. Since it is memory-based there is seldom a lot of space in **tmpfs** filesystems. **rootfs** is another memory-based filesystem, used only for holding the root directory before mounting something on it. In production there is usually a disk-based filesystem mounted on `/`.

You want to make your swap file on a disk-based filesystem, such as an **ext4** filesystem.

Comment: thanks alex.  can we use tmpfs for creating swap files? and how to check how much total space is available before creating swap. and how to check which is large filesystem. can we create swap using multiple filesystems?

Comment: Why would you use a **tmpfs** for swap file? **tmpfs** is memory-based; i don't see any useful purpose in creating a swap file in memory. Swap files are supposed to provide additional virtual memory.

Comment: it is larger than rootfs. that why i got doubt.

Comment: Please add the result of `df -h` to your question.

Comment: If the posted `df -h` is all you have then you really don't want any swap file.

Comment: how to create swap file for particular file system??

Comment: Allocate a file with `fallocate`, then format is as swap with `mkswap`, then activate it with `swapon`. If you want to make the activation permanent then add it to `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: Hi alex. i am able to create swap file but evry time it is taking space from one file system only is there any way to create swap file from particular filesystem

Comment: @saidesh: It will take space from the file system where you create it. I don't understand the problem.

Comment: It will take space from the file system where you create **swap fille**. i got it. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Answering your questions in order

> On which file system is the swap file created if multiple file systems are present? Can we externally specify from which file system to take?

A swapfile can be placed on any local filesystem. Such a filesystem should be backed by physical disk.

> I have two file systems `tmpfs` and `rootfs`, and by default swap file is created by using `rootfs` memory; even tmpfs has more size. What is tmpfs?

`tmpfs` is a temporary filesystem that comes directly from physical memory. If you have 8GB of physical memory could might decide to have a `tmpfs` filesystem of 2GB. There is a direct tradeoff between the amount of memory available in a `tmpfs` filesystem and the amount of memory available for the running system.

Your `rootfs` is a minimal memory-based boot image. Usually I would expect this to have been replaced with a true disk-based root filesystem but that hasn't happened here.

Do not create a swapfile on either the `rootfs` or `tmpfs` filesystems!

> Before creating swap file how to check if space is there or not?

The `df -h` command will show you available space per mountpoint. You can choose one (any one) that is backed by physical disk and that has enough space. In the tiny screenshot snippet there is nowhere shown that is suitable as you've only included the `rootfs` and `tmpfs` filesystems.

Comment: Hi roaima. i am able to create swap file but evry time it is taking space from one file system only is there any way to create swap file from particular filesystem

Comment: @saidesh yes of course. Let me know which part of my answer isn't clear and I'll see if I can expand it.

Answer (score 0):

> On which file system is the swap file created if multiple file systems are present? Can we externally specify from which file system to take?

The `fallocate` command is used to create, enlarge or shrink a file to a specified size. It will create that file wherever you tell it to do. It can also be used to "dig holes" in files, reducing the number of blocks they use on disk.

> I have two file systems tmpfs and rootfs, and by default swap file is created by using rootfs memory; even tmpfs has more size. What is tmpfs?

Despite popular belief, `tmpfs` is **not** a RAM based file system but a virtual memory based file system. That means its back-end is the sum of the on-disk swap area(s), which might be partitions or plain files, and the portion of RAM which is not used or reserved for other purposes. Of course, if you have not created any swap area, `tmpfs` is similar to a RAM based file system.

> Before creating swap file how to check if space is there or not?

Before creating a swap file, you need to find a file system with enough space. Virtual file systems like `rootfs` or `tmpfs` are not suitable for swap.  When `rootfs` is backed by RAM (ramfs), creating a substantial swap file on it will have disastrous effect, otherwise that would be like creating a swap file on `tmpfs` which is absolutely pointless, just like filling a tank with a liquid taken from this very tank.

Comment: Hi jlliagre. i am able to create swap file but evry time it is taking space from one file system only is there any way to create swap file from particular filesystem

Comment: That doesn't make sense. A file belongs to a single file system by design. Please better explain what is the problem you are trying to solve, and do not accept answers until one really answers to your question.

Comment: that means a swap file will be created by default from only one file system? is it like default?. i need to check which file system has more space and i want to create swap file from that file system only. is there any way to get it correct me if i am wrong

Comment: A swap file is a file. A file belong to a single file system. If you want to use a specific file system, create the swap file on that file system. If you want to use more than one file system, you can create multiple swap files. Only disk based file systems are suitable to create swap files.

Comment: for that simply we need to move to that file system and execute **fallocate -l "$size" "$swapfilename"** right? or

Comment: Please don't ask again the very same meaningless question. Explain the issue you are observing. There is no way to know what your command is doing without some context.

Comment: sorry. every time swap file s created from same filesystem even other filesystem has more free space. how to mention filesystem name while creating swap file

Comment: You accepted a reply which contains a misleading statement (or at least a wrong assumption). The file is created where the script ask it to be. This location is specified in the `swapfilename` variable but you fail to tell what this variable is set to.